# In C# XNA, how do I display my sprites in random places every time the game loads?

Tags: c#, random, xna

I am having trouble with loading my sprites in random places when the game loads, I have currently got them set in specific positions as shown below:

```
BlackBallRectangle = new Rectangle(150, 300, 25,25);
BlackBallRectangle2 = new Rectangle(500, 400, 25, 25);
BlueBallRectangle = new Rectangle(500, 150, 25, 25);
GreenBallRectangle = new Rectangle(100, 500, 25, 25);
OrangeBallRectangle = new Rectangle(180, 200, 25, 25);
PinkBallRectangle = new Rectangle(260, 260, 25, 25);
RedBallRectangle = new Rectangle(300, 450, 25, 25);
YellowBallRectangle = new Rectangle(550, 300, 25, 25);
```

I have created a `Random Randome = new Random();` but I am unsure if this is needed. Any help would be great as I need them to be in random places for each level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of `Random`.

```
Random Randome = new Random();
BlackBallRectangle = new Rectangle(Randome.Next(0, 150), Randome.Next(0, 300), 25, 25);
BlackBallRectangle2 = new Rectangle(Randome.Next(0, 500), Randome.Next(0, 400), 25, 25);
// the same thing for others
```

This `Randome.Next(0, 150)` generate a value between `0` and `150`. You can replace `minValue` and `maxValue` to match your needs.

**Note:** If you make same instance of the class with the `Random` property, I recommend you to mark it as `static`, otherwise there are chances to generate for same clases type same set of values.

Comment: You can do `Randome.Next(151)` or `Randome.Next(301)` too